# How inherit a custom controller in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

I try to inherit a custom controller from a custom module, my folders are the next

odoo/addons
odoo12/moduleWithTheController/controllers/as_controller.py
odoo12_myCustoms/myActualProject/as_read_controller.py

The controller that I want inherit is in odoo12/moduleWithTheController/controllers/as_controller.py and contains the next code

```
class as_webservice(http.Controller):
@http.route(['/account_fiscal/account','/account_fiscal/account/<account_id>','/account_fiscal/account/name/<ai>'], auth="public", type="http")
def account(self, account_id = None, ai=None, **post):
    #some code here
```

I try to inherit this controller in odoo12_myCustoms/myActualProject/as_read_controller.py

with the next code but it doesnt works

```
from myActualProject.controllers.main import as_webservice as RC
```

class as_webservice_2(RC):

```
@http.route(['/account_fiscal/account','/account_fiscal/account/<account_id>','/account_fiscal/account/name/<ai>'], auth="public", type="http")
def account(self, account_id = None, ai=None, **post):
#some code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```html
from odoo.addons.yourmodulename.controllers.yourpythonfilename import warehouse
```

Answer (score 0):

Just import the controller class and use python [inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#tut-inheritance).

If the controller class is defined inside the `odoo12_myCustoms/myActualProject/as_read_controller.py` file, use the following syntax:

```
from odoo.addons.myActualProject.as_read_controller import ControllerClassName


class Extension(ControllerClassName):
    @route()
    def handler(self):
        do_before()
        return super(Extension, self).handler()
```

You can find an example in the [website_crm](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/website_crm/controllers/main.py#L6) module.